# Eclipse: Project cannot reference itself

Tags: java, eclipse

I am not able to add `Dynamic Web Module 3.0` facet due to this error. No idea what is wrong with my project settings. 
This is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928277/eclipse-problem-project-references-itself) question but accepted answer provides a url as solution which no longer work.

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: Question subject is the error.

Comment: Where's the duplicate? What exactly were you doing in the UI when this message appeared? What kind of project is it?

Comment: Updated my question with link to duplicate question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Deleted .classpath and project settings files from project folder. Then imported the maven project again.
It works fine after that.

Answer (score 9):

Please delete

> < wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/"/ >

from **org.eclipse.wst.common.component** under **.settings** folder.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason just deleting the error in the eclipse solved the problem for me.
It said that the problem may reoccurs after reloading or building but it did not

p.s.
I'm using mars version